# Large scale deployment of a .net mono app on Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: .net, linux, deployment, mono, setup-deployment

We have a .net app written to be Mono and Linux compatible - written in Visual Studio 2010. For deployment on Windows, we use a Visual Studio Deployment project to build the installer and put files in the correct places.

Is there an equivalent for Linux? Some thing that's as easy and simple for the end user to install?

Thanks

Roberto

Comment: did you look into monodevelop? (http://monodevelop.com/)

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu, you really want to work within the .deb/apt-based packaging framework the distro already provides (the same applies to Debian derivatives generally; other distro families have their own systems e.g RPM).  See the [Debian guidelines for packaging CLI based applications/binaries](http://pkg-mono.alioth.debian.org/cli-policy/index.html).  It'd probably also be well worth taking a look at how existing mono-based apps are packaged (e.g MonoDevelop, F-Stop, Tomboy).